# TypeLoadException after compile unity editor script into dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have compiled our editor scripts into a single .dll file, and put it in `/Assets/Editor` directory:

[image]

These extended script menus are shown in editor correctly:

[image]

But it has this TypeLoadException when I click the menu. The type 'Util' is actually in 'UnityVS.x3dgame.CSharp.csproj' project, which is also a library project.

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Util' from assembly 'EditorLibrary'.
Scene2DBundleTool.GenerateSceneEffectLuaEditor ()
```

[image]

I have no idea how to solve this.

Here is some more information:
Solution structure:

[image]

EditorLibrary references:

[image]

Help wanted.

Comment: Did you try what's in the answer?

Comment: I don't quite get your point, I had added references to the .dlls you mentioned before.

Comment: The point in my answer is that when you use Unity API in your dll library, you are supposed to add reference to library before building it. If you have already done that, you should have left a comment to let me know about that otherwise there is no way I would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you did not build the dll it properly. If you want to include Unity's API in your own dll, you must add also add Unity reference to the dll so that your dll can use those API.

You must the basic references such as, *System*, *System.Core* and *System.Xml*.

Now, you must add Unity's references to your dll project before build the dll project. The dll reference to add depends on where the Unity API came from.

**Standalone API**:

- UnityEngine.dll - from *C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed*

**Editor API**:

- UnityEditor.dll - from  *C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed*

**UI**:

- UnityEngine.UI.dll - from C:\Program
  *Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem*

  [Editor features]:
- UnityEditor.UI.dll - from C:\Program
  *Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Editor*

Finally, make sure to select the proper .NET framework in your dll project before building it. *.Net Framework 2.0* should be fine.

Our Unity's path may be different but once you find the root path where it is installed, everything else is the-same.

Note:

<sup>When I said, add reference, I meant add reference to the library project you are building not to your Unity project. From Visual Studio, this can be done by going to **Projects** ---> **Add Reference...** ---> **Browse...(Button)** then select the appropriate dll file.</sup>

Comment: After more checking, I find out that some code in "UnityVS.x3dgame.CSharp" project is actually not compiled into the dll. 
The "Util" and "Singleton" class actually not exist in the dll. Thanks though.